# ember-cli-mirage loses relationship when models are sideloaded

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I've got following models:

```
// venue.js
export default Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

// web.js
export default Model.extend({
  webname: DS.attr('string'),
  venue: DS.belongsTo('venue', {async: false})
});
```

and I use the `RESTAdapter`. I defined my Mirage configuration as following:

```
// serializers/application.js
import { RestSerializer } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default RestSerializer.extend({
});

// config.js
export default function() {
  this.get('/webs', schema => {
    let venue = schema.venues.create({name: 'venue name'});
    let web = schema.webs.create({
      webname: 'web name',
      venue: venue
    });


    return {
      web: web,
      venue: venue
    }
  })
}
```

This model sideloading is a part of our application, so I have to use it. Anyways as you can see the response is fine here, i.e. it correctly identifies the foreign keys etc:

[image: chrome tools]

But when I receive the response I can't access the venue from the web - it's `null`. The ember inspector confirms that:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea of how I can preserve the relationship when I obtain the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it a bit wrong apparently. Here is how one should do the sideloading correctly.

- Since my `web` requires a `venue` to be sideloaded, I created a new model-specific serializer by calling `ember g mirage-serializer web`. Then I can specify the relationships which should be loaded alongside with the main entity via the `include` field:

```
// serializers/web.js
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';

export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  include: ['venue'],
});
```

- Then the `config.js` can be changed to

```
// config.js
  this.get('/webs', schema => {
    let venue = schema.venues.create({name: 'venue name', id: 100});
    let web = schema.webs.create({
      webname: 'web name',
      venueId: 100
    });

    return web;
  })

// OR

  this.get('/webs', schema => {
    let venue = schema.venues.create({name: 'venue name', id: 100});
    let web = schema.webs.create({
      webname: 'web name',
      venue: venue
    });

    return web;
  })
```

or one can use fixture files etc.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you found `include`! The idea there is that whether associations are included or not can depend on the request. For example, with JSON:API a lot of apps will use [query param includes](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/data-layer/serializers#relationships) to specify inclusion from the client-side. Other apps will have their servers send over default server-side includes, and that's what the `include` key is used for.

Also note that `include` can be a function, if you want more dynamic behavior. You can [check out the docs](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/api/modules/serializer~Serializer#include) for some examples.

Last point – your `get` handlers really should be returning what's already in Mirage's database, rather than creating new resources then returning them. This way your app will behave more similar to how it will in production.

So instead of

```js
this.get('/webs', schema => {
  let venue = schema.venues.create({name: 'venue name', id: 100});
  let web = schema.webs.create({
    webname: 'web name',
    venueId: 100
  });

  return web;
})
```

try

```js
this.get('/webs', schema => {
  return schema.webs.all().models[0]
})
```

to return the first model (or `schema.webs.all()` if the endpoint should return a collection). Then, to seed Mirage with your starting data, put your data creation logic in `scenarios/default.js` using `server.create`:

```js
// scenarios/default.js
export default function(server) {
  let venue = server.create('venue', {name: 'venue name', id: 100});
  server.create('web', {
    venue,
    webname: 'web name'
  });
}
```